# PHPStan caching strategy per branch

Tags: gitlab, devops, gitlab-ci, phpstan

I'm using Gitlab to deploy my codebase.
Each time, I deploy a branch (in fact multiple times by day), my CI do the following things (very simplified) :

#1 Create a specific deploy folder with my branch name and clone whole project inside

```
branch-1
/data/www/branch-1/....
branch-2
/data/www/branch-2/....
```

#2 Run PHPStan (with no overriden configuration)

```
- cd /data/www/branch-1
- bin/phpstan analyze --level 1 --no-progress
```

So, by default my caching folder is set to `/tmp/phpstan`. This folder is getting bigger and bigger.
For now, I have a cron that delete the folder periodically but it seems like a workaround...

Can I use a better approach in my CI/CD to maintain a reasonnable `/tmp/phpstan` folder size and not broke the performance of caching ?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're using the `shell` executor, so one solution would be to [switch to using the `docker` executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/). The `docker` executor will run all your pipeline's jobs inside a Docker container, and when it finishes, the container (and all data within) is destroyed, so each time a job runs it has a fresh slate.

The second option is to clear `/tmp/phpstan` after you run `bin/phpstan` (unless it causes other problems, you'd have to look into that):

```yaml
- cd /data/www/branch-1
- bin/phpstan analyze --level 1 --no-progress
- rm -r /tmp/phpstan/*
```

The second solution is easier, but running your jobs in Docker has a bunch of other benefits, most importantly that you don't need to install packages on the host where the Runner process exists, but rather in the Docker image used.